# I have a following gcc compilation warning

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

```
  symbol.h:179: note: expected ‘uintptr_t *’ but argument is of type ‘PRECEDENCE’
```

The corresponding code is :

```
176 void            symbol_SetCount(SYMBOL, unsigned long);
177 unsigned long   symbol_GetCount(SYMBOL);
178 
179 size_t             symbol_Ordering(uintptr_t*, SYMBOL);
180 
181 void            symbol_CheckIndexInRange(int);
182 void            symbol_CheckNoVariable(SYMBOL);
```

SYMBOL is defined as:

```
typedef size_t SYMBOL
```

Any effort will be highly appreciated.

PRECEDENCE  has been  modified as:

```
typedef int *PRECEDENCE;


int        symbol_Ordering(PRECEDENCE, SYMBOL);
```

here is some additional information of symbol_Ordering:

```
 if (symbol_Equal(propSymbol, eml_Id())) 
{  /* Arguments should be nil, propositional */
symbol_SetOrdering(Precedence, fol_Equality(), symbol_Ordering(Precedence, eml_Id()));
return eml_RplacWithOpAndArgs(Atom, fol_Equality(), Args)}

int  symbol_ORDERING;


int symbol_GetIncreasedOrderingCounter(void)
```

{
    return symbol_ORDERING++;
       }

```
 static __inline__ BOOL symbol_PrecedenceGreater(PRECEDENCE P, SYMBOL S1, SYMBOL S2)
{
return symbol_Ordering((uintptr_t*)P, S1) < symbol_Ordering((uintptr_t*)P, S2);
 }

 size_t             symbol_Ordering(uintptr_t*, SYMBOL);
```

Comment: You probably also need to show the code that calls `symbol_Ordering`.

Comment: So what is `PRECEDENCE` defined to be?

Comment: PRECENDENCE has been defined as:

    typedef int *PRECEDENCE;

Comment: Well, the error says the problem. The function doesn't want an `int*`, it wants a `uintptr_t*`.

Comment: @thetna I have a feeling the code you have posted is not (for one reason or another) the code you are compiling.

Comment: @GMan Assuming its in a header file, and given the syntax, it's a declaration, which doesn't get to choose what it wants :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple declarations of `symbol_Ordering` - one that takes a `uintptr_t*` and one that takes an `int*`. `uintptr_t*` and `int*` aren't the same type (one is signed, one is unsigned), so don't do that. Make the types match.

Comment: I have added some more information. Does that information is sufficient to give explicit solution?